# Rewrite url but a list?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

suppose I wanted to redirect everything that gets sent http://website.com/create to index.php?p=create

Basically I will have a list of available pages such as (create, signup, login, etc), everything else I need rewritten to index.php?p=view&code=whatever_is_sent

I tried to following but it's failing and I have no idea how to exclude a list of pages out of the array

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?p=view&name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ?p=view&name=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(create|signup|login)/?$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?p=view&code=$1
```